# multiline regex match & text wrappers

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract a text that is wrapped by

```
Answer:
--------
```

and

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Example:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
Answer:
--------
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So the expected output would be:

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

too few details to buid the regular expression but I would find the position of the first marker (--------), then find the position of the your second marker and then retrieve the sub-string between them.

Answer (score 0):

This regex matches exactly what you want:

```
(?sm)Answer:\R+-{8}\R+\K.*?(?=\R+-{80})
```

See the match in **[the Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/gM4pI1/8)**.

This will work in Perl and the PCRE engine (available for instance in PHP, R and Notepad++). On many other engines, this variation will work:

```
(?sm)(?<=Answer:\n-{8}).*?(?=\n-{80})
```

Note that on Windows you would want `\r\n` in two places instead of `\n`.

**Explanation**

- `(?s)` activates `DOTALL` mode, allowing the dot to match across lines
- `(?m)` turns on multi-line mode, allowing `^` and `$` to match on each line
- `Answer:` matches literal chars
- `\R+` matches line breaks
- `-{8}` matches eight hyphens
- `\R+` matches line breaks
- The `\K` tells the engine to drop what was matched so far from the final
- `.*?` lazily matches any chars up to...
- a point where the lookahead `(?=\R+-{80})` can assert that what follows is line breaks then eighty hyphens

**Reference**

- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)
- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)